# docker-py getarchive destination folder

Tags: python, docker, raw-data, dockerpy

I am following the instructions given in this link for get_archive()[link](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/#get_archive)
 but instead of creating my container i was trying to use already running container in my case "docker-nginx" as an input string and also the destination folder where my content was residing in nginx server as '/usr/share/nginx/html' and got my output for the stat of the folder too i want to know how can i give the destination folder in this function if not where is my extrated tar file ? i was not able to figure out where my file was downloaded

here is my code
`strm,stat=c.get_archive(container_name,'/usr/share/nginx/html')`

my output for print(strm) is `<requests.packages.urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x7fe3581e1250>`

my output for print(stat) is `{u'linkTarget': u'', u'mode': 2147484157, u'mtime': u'2016-10-05T09:37:17.928258508-05:00', u'name': u'html', u'size': 4096}`

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on which version of the docker sdk you're using.

**For `docker` sdk versions pre-3.X**

`get_archive` returns a file-like stream. So, use `shutil.copyfileobj` to stream the data to a file:

```
import shutil

strm, stat = container.get_archive(container_name, path_in_container)
with open('out.html', 'w') as outfile:
    shutil.copyfileobj(strm, outfile)
```

**For `docker` sdk 3.X+**

`get_archive` returns an iterator over the file's content, so just iterate and write:

```
strm, stat = container.get_archive(container_name, path_in_container)
with open('out.html', 'w') as outfile:
    for d in strm:
        outfile.write(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

Answers above are partially true. If you write tar stream directly, it writes extra unkown metadata parameters.

In order to write only content, please use following,

```
from io import StringIO
strm,status = container.get_archive("container_path/")
for d in strm:
   pw_tar = tarfile.TarFile(fileobj=StringIO(d.decode('utf-8')))
   pw_tar.extractall("extract_to/")
```

folder or file can be extracted from stream.

Comment: When I use this code to copy a directory from container to host, I get the below error. Any idea on how to fix this ?                                                                                         
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 750, in __read
    raise ReadError("unexpected end of data")
tarfile.ReadError: unexpected end of data

Answer (score 0):

I found out how this function works what it does it returns raw response of a requests made to our container. raw response explaination can be found [in this link](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content) 
in order to extract raw content we can use this code so that we can simply read our raw data as text format according to the output file in my case html.

```
raw_data=strm.read()
f= open('out.html', 'w')
f.write(raw_data)
```